# How to view outline of a custom UIView in a Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

I made a custom UIView for a project. I know how to insert it in a StoryBoard (as a generic view, then by specifying its class), and it compiles and runs fine. However, the custom view is rendered in the storyboard as a white rectangle without a visible border. It means that when the view is unselected, it becomes invisible on the storyboard if the window background is white. It is then very difficult to adjust its position/size, and it's going to be really painful when I will add more views.

I perfectly understand that the storyboard does not provide any kind of rendering and I'm not asking for this, but is there any solution to display the boundaries of the view as a simple border so I can still view it without having to select it ?

Comment: If it were me, I'd set the view's background color to a grey temporarily.

Comment: @CodaFi Doesn't even have to be temporary -- you can leave the background grey in the storyboard editor and then simply set it to its correct color in the code when the view is loaded. If one line of code simplifies working with the storyboard, that line is well-spent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two options in the menu `Editor->Canvas`, `Show bounds rectangles` and `Show layout rectangles` which are exactly what I was looking for!